# returning struct in solidity

Tags: solidity, struct, return

I have seen [here](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/1994/does-solidity-allow-struct-return-types) that we can return struct for internal functions.
Why can we not just return struct for a non-internal (= public) function?

Also, I can see in the [same](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/1994/does-solidity-allow-struct-return-types) link **"structs would have to be integrated into the ABI"**. What does this line mean?

Comment: for "structs would have to be integrated into the ABI" he mean if you want to do a return of struct with external function you need to put this structure inside the ABI declaration.

Comment: How that can be done? Is there any documentation related to that? any link will be very helpful.